# Adding DbItem under media library with FakeDb

Tags: fakedb

When using FakeDb, and I set the full path of a DbItem to go under the media library, the path gets changed to the /sitecore/content/home/image-item.

```
    //Method starts here
    public void MediaItemPath()
    {
        Sitecore.Data.ID mediaItemId = Sitecore.Data.ID.NewID;

        // create some media item. Location, fields and template are not important
        using (Sitecore.FakeDb.Db db = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Db())
        {
            var mediaFakeItem = new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbItem("my-image", mediaItemId);
            mediaFakeItem.FullPath = "/sitecore/media library/my-image";
            db.Add(mediaFakeItem);
            Sitecore.Data.Items.Item mediaItem = db.GetItem(mediaItemId);

            Assert.AreEqual("/sitecore/media library/my-image", mediaFakeItem.FullPath);

        }
    }
```

How can I add an item to the media library?

Comment: Do you have these entries in your APP_Config '<mediaLibrary>
 <mediaProvider type="Sitecore.Fakes.FakeMediaProvider, Sitecore.Fakes"/>
 </mediaLibrary>'

Comment: It's a [bug](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/issues/172).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API is not quite obvious here. By default, all the items are added to the *content*. If you need to add an item to the Media Library, you should set the `fakeItem.ParentID` property:

```
    var mediaFakeItem = new DbItem("my-image")
    {
      ParentID = Sitecore.ItemIDs.MediaLibraryRoot
    };
```

Since `DbItem` has got mutable `ParentID` and `FullPath` properties, it's quite challenging to keep them in sync (e.g. when you change the `FullPath` only). I created a FakeDb [issue](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/issues/172) to address it (if possible without introducing breaking changes).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have media config in App.config

```
<mediaLibrary>
      <!-- MEDIA PROVIDER -->
      <mediaProvider type="Sitecore.FakeDb.Resources.Media.FakeMediaProvider, Sitecore.FakeDb" />
    </mediaLibrary>
```

Also try this below code :

```
public void HowToMockMediaItemProvider()
    {
      const string MyImageUrl = "~/media/myimage.ashx";
      Sitecore.Data.ID mediaItemId = Sitecore.Data.ID.NewID;

      // create some media item. Location, fields and template are not important
      using (Sitecore.FakeDb.Db db = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Db
      {
        new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbItem("my-image", mediaItemId)
      })
      {
        Sitecore.Data.Items.Item mediaItem = db.GetItem(mediaItemId);

        // create media provider mock and configure behaviour
        Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider mediaProvider =
          NSubstitute.Substitute.For<Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider>();

        mediaProvider
          .GetMediaUrl(Arg.Is<Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem>(i => i.ID == mediaItemId))
          .Returns(MyImageUrl);

        // substitute the original provider with the mocked one
        using (new Sitecore.FakeDb.Resources.Media.MediaProviderSwitcher(mediaProvider))
        {
          string mediaUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem);
          Xunit.Assert.Equal(MyImageUrl, mediaUrl);
        }
      }
    }
```

Source : https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki/Media

Comment: I did try that method; however, the path of the mediaItem is still under "/sitecore/content/my-image."  For my purposes, I cared more about the actual location of the mediaItem rather than the Url of the media item.  I had a Sitecore Query that was checking under the media library.